# While loop session?

Tags: php, session

I'm creating a website in where the user creates an account, and a session is started. Then, you're led to a page with accounts made by you (I'm not giving you the reason why, it will make sense with the idea, and I'm not giving you the reason so no one will steal my idea :D) , and you have to click on one of them. Once you do, I want the script to create a new session based on what you click. The problem right now is that I don't think the if(isset( is actually running in the while loop, so it when I click on an account it takes me to a random account created by me, not the one I clicked on. Code :
login.php (part of it)

```
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: ....php");
```

accounts.php

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
   echo"
<form action='.....php' method='POST'>
<input type='submit'  name='submit_bubble' id='submit_bubble' style='position:relative;margin-left:500px;margin-top:100px;width:400px;height:400px;border-radius:400px;font-family:Tahoma,Arial;font-size:25px;' value='$profile'/>
";

echo "
</input>
</form>
";
if (isset($_POST['submit_bubble'])) {
$_SESSION['profile'] = $profile;
header ("Location:gridtest.php");
}
}

?>
```

header.php (for the rest of the website)

```
include ( 'mysql_connectinc.php' );
include ( 'functions.php');
function sec_session_start() {
            $session_name = 'username'; // Set a custom session name
            $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
            $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

            ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
            $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
            session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
            session_name($username); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
            session_start(); // Start the php session
            session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
        }
          $user = $_SESSION['profile'];
          $_SESSION['id'] = 'profile';
```

Comment: No one wants to steal your idea.

Comment: And its a complicated idea... would take a while to explain but I have an entire reason for making this website

Comment: i dont want you to steal my code, so i cant answer the question

Comment: Oh you have an entire reason for making it.  Cool.  Most web sites are made for absolutely no reason at all.   (Seriously we're not going to be able to answer your question with the tiny amount of information you've given us).

Comment: No, I don't care about the code, you can copy the code, its just the idea... fine here it is. You log in to choose another account to login by. Now the reason behind this you really don't have to know. Sorry if I'm sounding arrogant.

Comment: Okay, here. You create an account. It inserts into the database with a type of default, and then when you log in you create more accounts without a password with the type not set as default. Is that enough info? When you click on an account, I want a session to be started with that account name. Eg my default account is Johny apple seed. I log in. I can choose to use the website as MIcheal, Ramen, etc.

Comment: Sorry for missing info, please don't downvote me, I tried giving sufficent info, if you need anything else, let me know :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['profile'] = $profile;
```

should be

```
$_SESSION['profile'] = $_POST['submit_bubble'];
```

`submit_bubble` is the input name

Comment: Thank you so much you will no believe how happy you made me! Thank you I owe you one you saved my entire night :D. Thanks!